# PHP error: “syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'” on my site

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following syntax error while giving this code

```
<?php
if($pages >= 1){

    for($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++){

        echo '<a href="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are opening another `<?php` block in echo.

```
echo '<a href="'.$row['id'].'?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
echo '<a href="'. $row['id'].'?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
```